# Create data validation list when some of the values have commas?

Tags: vba, validation, excel

I am creating a data validation list using the following method:

```
sDataValidationList = sDataValidationList & wksCalculation.Cells(r, lActivityNoColumn).value & ","
```

Then I apply it to a cell using:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=s
```

This works well most of the time, but when any of the `wksCalculation.Cells(r, lActivityNoColumn).value` contain commas, then those strings are split by the data validation list and each comma separated part of the string is shown as a separate item.

How can I modify my code to be useful also when some of the values that go into the data validation list have commas in them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In data validation with `Type:=xlValidateList` the `Formula1` can either be a comma separated list or a formula string which is a reference to a range with that list. In a comma separated list the comma has special meaning. In a  reference to a range it has not.

So supposed your list, which you are concatenating from `wksCalculation.Cells(r, lActivityNoColumn)`, is in `Sheet2!A1:A5` then

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet2!A1:A5"
```

will work.

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & wksCalculation.Range("A1:A5").Address(External:=True)
```

should also work.

Answer (score 6):

You will have to Trick Excel ;)

Here is an example. Replace that comma with a similar looking character whose ASC code is `0130`

```
Dim dList As String

dList = Range("B14").Value

'~~> Replace comma with a similar looking character
dList = Replace(dList, ",", Chr(130))

With Range("D14").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=dList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

[image]

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm having the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703424/c-sharp-interop-format-validation-list ... can you please tell me the equivalent of your code in C# Interop?

Answer (score 2):

Create a named range `ValidValues` that contains your list items; use that named range in the data validation formula `=ValidValues`. If the number of valid values can change, I suggest you make the named range refer to a table column, like `SomeTable[SomeColumn]` - that way any new value in that column will automatically be part of the named range and thus, automatically added to the list of valid values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASCI character "ALT-0130". This will look like a comma but it won't be used to separate in the validation.