# data validation list with a vba array

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to create a data validation list using vba code. The array generate itself depending on many variable.

here is the code i am using

```
            For iter4 = 2 To nbWsheet

            If Wsheet.Cells(iter4, 2) = Cat And Wsheet.Cells(iter4, ColMod) = "x" And Wsheet.Cells(iter4, ColStd) = "oui" Then

                TableValue = Wsheet.Cells(iter4, 4).Value & " - " & Wsheet.Cells(iter4, 7).Value
                Table = Table & "," & TableValue

            End If

        Next iter4

        'Ajout de la list
        With Cells(iGlob, 5).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=Table
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = ""
            .ShowError = ""
        End With
```

The problem with this code, is the text in the table contain ",". When the data validation list is generated, every time it see a "," it put the text on a new line...

Is there a way to keep the "," inside the table

Exemple of what i want to display : 123456 - Engine, 300HP

Hope i was clear,

Thanks,

Comment: You almost clear... but can you show the data you try to use. May be a screenshot.

Comment: The only way I know of to do this is to output your list to a range of cells, and then set Formula1 to reference that range of cells.  You could hide the cells, or put it in a hidden worksheet.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724178/create-data-validation-list-when-some-of-the-values-have-commas) for the same question and some innovative answers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an escape character for the comma in custom list. According to [MSDN Validation.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840078.aspx), the comma always separate the entries.

One workaround is to use Dynamic Named Range.

1. Use a spare column in a hidden sheet or somewhere, lets use Column A for demo
2. In A1, put in "DV_ListTable", Define the cell with name **DV_ListTable**
3. Highlight Column A, Define it as **DV_ListColumn**
4. Define another name using Name Manager as **DV_List** with RefersTo as
   `=OFFSET(DV_ListTable,1,0,IF(COUNTA(DV_ListColumn)-1=0,1,COUNTA(DV_ListColumn)-1))`
   [image: ResultingNameManager]

Now the Data Validation will be (cell D1):
[image: DV]

Then the macro to change this dynamic range contents will be:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeDataValidationList()
    Dim i As Long, Table As String, TableValue As String
    Dim oRng As Range, oValues As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook
        ' Build up the new table list
        Table = .Names("DV_ListTable").RefersToRange.Value ' Header
        ' For Demo, the data is from Columns next to the DV_ListTable
        Set oRng = .Names("DV_ListTable").RefersToRange.Offset(0, 1)
        Do Until IsEmpty(oRng)
            TableValue = oRng.Value & " - " & oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Table = Table & vbCrLf & TableValue
            Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
        Set oRng = Nothing
        ' Clear the contents in the column
        .Names("DV_ListColumn").RefersToRange.ClearContents
        ' Paste in the values separated by vbCrLf
        oValues = Application.Transpose(Split(Table, vbCrLf))
        .Names("DV_ListTable").RefersToRange.Resize(UBound(oValues)) = oValues
        Set oValues = Nothing
    End With
End Sub
```

Sample screenshot after "ChangeDataValisationList" executed:
[image: screenshot]

Hope this helps you on the right direction for a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "," with Chr(44).  The Chr function returns a string based on the VBA character code.  I find it also comes in handy when you want to insert a double-quote (Chr(34) for a double quote).

Comment: This will still result in the same issue being asked about.  OP has data that needs to be on a single line in the drop-down list, but that data contains a comma (example: `123456 - Engine, 300HP`).  But the comma is causing the validation list to split the entry into two (`123456 - Engine` and `300HP`, when it should be a single entry.  Replacing the commas with `Chr(44)` will result in the same issue.  This does not answer or resolve the question.