# Excel VBA: how to add data validation list which contain comma included value without using reference of Range

Tags: vba, excel

I need to add a data validation list to Cell whose few values contains comma.
I have the same problem like this [Data Validation to Include Comma Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722398/data-validation-to-include-comma-character)

But I can't reference a range, because I am creating a new workbook and feed its cell with the data validation list. So reference is not working for me and since some values contain comma so I can't set the **Range** into **String** and use that after **Formula1**

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=myStr
```

Another idea I found that I can replace comma with other character(dummy character) and after populating the cell replace that dummy character with comma but problem is that **how to replace that dummy character with comma ?**

Another way is that override the Formula1 so that I can use dummy character as delimiter but I don't know how to achieve this.

Please suggest any solution, my final goal is to create a new workbook and populate it with data validation list through **Excel VBA**

Comment: Can you not just create a new Worksheet and drop your list there, then reference it?

Comment: I can, but problem is comma containing values. If I store whole item in **myStr** then list validation automatically split them too into new items. Which I don't need.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724178/create-data-validation-list-when-some-of-the-values-have-commas), especially Siddharth's answer using `chr(130)` - which looks like a comma, but is not one.

Comment: Siddharth's answer is little helpful but can I change that **Chr(130)** to **comma** through any method

Comment: If Chr(130) looks identical to a comma why would you need to change it?

Comment: Because I have to match that String at server when I upload it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use the **dummy character** method for cell **B9**.  This sets up the *DV*:

```
Sub InternalString2()
    Range("B9").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=Replace("alpha%ralpha,beta%waiter,gamma%hammer,delta%faucet","%",Chr(130))
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = False
    End With
End Sub
```

where **Chr(130)** is the **dummy**.  The `.ShowError` is important.

Now to replace the **dummy**, we use the *Event Macro*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B9").Replace What:=Chr(130), Replacement:=","
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Its not working. Its only change selected list item's dummy character, not the whole items.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to this where Chr(130) is used as the dummy character. This will meet all @civam requirements of looking like a comma on the list and actually exporting as a comma after selection.

Comment: @snoopen  Thanks for the improvement!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer states, the comma cannot be escaped. The only solution, as far as I can see, is to add an extra worksheet to your new workbook, add the values there for your list, name that range, hide that sheet, and reference the named range. It's a fair few steps but really the only way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that is not my requirement.

Comment: I appreciate that it's not your requirement however this would be the only way to have a true comma in your list. I'd recommend Chr(130) as @vacip suggested if you don't want to create the separate worksheet.

Comment: I have created a dummy workbook and every time code runs it saves that with new file name.

Comment: I'm curious if you tried the updated solution proposed by @Gary'sStudent with Chr(130)? I would have thought it would have been the ideal solution as it eliminates the need for an additonal worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

As the @snoopen suggest, I have create a **Dummy Workbook** which contains the data validation list and every time code runs it save as the **Dummy Workbook** to desired new file name. After that it populates that sheet with required data.