# Numeric data validation list generated with VBA for Excel with locales in which the decimal separator is a comma

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to program some VBA code that creates a dropdown menu in a certain cell of an Excel Worksheet. The synatx is clear, The doubles that should be in the list are collected in the array MyList(). I use the following approach to set the data validation as follows:

```
Range("A1").Validation.Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
```

I (and the users of my program) work on a computer with the locale set to German. This includes that the decimal separator is a comma, while the separator of a validation list is a ";". As a result, if MyList contains the three values (3, 4.268, 5), the dropdown menu will show the four numbers (3, 4, 268, 5).

Of course, a workaround would be to first print the values either to some cells in the same worksheet or to a different (possibly hidden) worksheet. However, I consider this quite an ugly approach.

I also tried to convert the doubles to a string with a dot as decimal separator. However, there are two problems with that: for one, my sorting routine doesn't work anymore, it now sorts the values e.g. as (1, 10, 100, 2, 26, 3, 30, 300, etc.). Secondly, and even more important, Excel now interpretes the data also as a string. Later on in the code, I read out the data again and first would need to transform the data back from a string to back to a double. Also, there are some worksheet functions that also use this value, so I would also need that conversion in worksheet functions.

As there will be a larger body of users and this application only a smaller one, changing the locale settings of Excel or Windows is also not an option.

I couldn't get the dummy character method described here to work: [Excel VBA: how to add data validation list which contain comma included value without using reference of Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682142/excel-vba-how-to-add-data-validation-list-which-contain-comma-included-value-wi). For me, the replacement seems not to work: The dropdown menu has only one entry that contains the whole string still separated by the dummy character.

So the question is: Is there a way to generate a validation list directly in VBA with a locale which uses the comma as decimal separator?

Comment: `Application.DecimalSeparator` might be helpful.

Comment: Very good idea. However, I included Application.DecimalSeparator = "." at the beginning of my sub and reset it at the end. Unfortunately, this does not change the result, 31.6 is still considered as the two items 31 and 6 in the dropdown list. Do I maybe need to change a different application variable for the conversion of VBA doubles to the list strings?

Comment: I meant more along the lines of using `Application.DecimalSeparator` inside the `Join`, instead of the hard-coded `","`. Haven't tested if that actually works though.