# C# Interop format Validation List

Tags: c#, excel, interop, vsto

I implemented a code that adds Data Validation on cells from a specified range, but the values that contain `,` are chunked into pieces...

This is my code

```
var listFormats = new List<string>();
listFormats.Add("US punctuation + alphanumeric lowercase:[a-z0-9,.?;:!&()_'" + '"' + "]+");
listFormats.Add("US punctuation + alphanumeric uppercase:[A-Z0-9,.?;:!&()_'" + '"' + "]+");
listFormats.Add("US punctuation + alphanumeric mixedcase:[A-Za-z0-9,.?;:!&()_'" + '"' + "]+");
var flatListFormats = string.Join(",", listFormats.ToArray());

rng.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, flatListDelimiters, Type.Missing);
```

And this is what I get in the Validation List:
[image]

Instead of

```
US punctuation + alphanumeric lowercase:[a-z0-9,.?;:!&()_'"]+  
US punctuation + alphanumeric uppercase:[A-Z0-9,.?;:!&()_'"  
US punctuation + alphanumeric mixedcase:[A-Za-z0-9,.?;:!&()_'"
```

Comment: `XlDVType.xlValidateList` basically make the cells a drop down box. The best you can do is using `xlValidateCustom` and a crafty formula, since excel doesn't support regex in formulas, but vba does.

Comment: There are two decent answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724178/create-data-validation-list-when-some-of-the-values-have-commas

Comment: I have no idea how to convert the vba code from that answers to c# ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the list into a range and reference the range for the data validation.  Here's some pseudo code to get you started:

```
// Get the list you want into a cell range
worksheet.Range("A1:A3").Value = listFormats;

// Reference the range when applying the validation
rng.Validation.Delete();
rng.Validation.Add(... xlBetween, "='" + worksheet.Name + "'!" + worksheet.Range("A1:A3").Address);
```

Comment: This is what I get in the Validation List after implementing it: `$K$2:$K$11`

Comment: @Valip Good point.  You'd need to add the "=" + ...  I updated my answer.

Comment: Should this also work if I'm referencing a range from other worksheet than the one that should contain the Validation List?

Comment: @Valip No.  In that case, you'd have to append the sheet name with the `!`.  I'll update my answer again...  The better way would be to name the range and scope it to the workbook.